# Average VBA function

Tags: arrays, vba, runtime-error

I'm getting

> Run-time error '424': Object required"

every time I try this, I don't get why!

```
Dim CCAnual(1 To 200) As Currency
For i = 1 To 188
    Set CCAnual(i) = Applications.WorksheetFunction.Average(Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 14, 5)))
Next i
For i = 189 To 200
    Set CCAnual(i) = Applications.WorksheetFunction.Average(Worksheets(3).Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(200, 5)))
Next i
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried it both defining the worksheet as it is, with ActiveWorksheet and with nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1st issue* is here `CCAnual(i) = Applications.WorksheetFunction`

use this:
    `CCAnual(i) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 14, 5)))`

or this:
    `CCAnual(i) = Application.Average(Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 14, 5)))`

or this: 
    `CCAnual(i) = Evaluate("=Average(" & Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 14, 5)).Address & ")")`

---

also you should keep in mind that you may be faced with *2nd issue*, is that `.Average()` does not work with empty cells, so at least one of the cells should be numeric value

---

so finally your code should be something like this:

```
 Sub test()
     Dim CCAnual(1 To 200) As Currency
     For i = 1 To 188
         If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 14, 5))) = 0 Then 
             Exit For
         Else
             CCAnual(i) = Application.Average(Range(Cells(i + 2, 5), Cells(i + 14, 5)))
         End if
     Next i
     ''''''''''
 End Sub
```